# BeautifulSoup not extracting image alt text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am in the very preliminary stages of creating a web scraper. I'm still pretty new to Python. I'm trying to extract star ratings from a web page. This is meant to find a list of all img alt text in a page and print it to console.

```
url = 'https://www.nhtsa.gov/vehicle/2017/FORD/ESCAPE/SUV/AWD#safety-ratings-frontal' #url to retrieve data from
html = '<div class="col-sm-6"><img src="/sites/nhtsa.dot.gov/themes/nhtsa_gov/images/star-rating/5.png" alt="5 star" class="vehicle-base-details--rating"></div>' #temporary-- for testing
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all('div'): #lists all image alt text
    for img in div.find_all('img', alt=True):
        print(img['alt'])
```

When I replace "page" with "html" on line 4, BeautifulSoup is able to extract what I need and prints "5 star". The issue is when I try to get the HTML directly from the web page. I have tried searching by the object's class as well and I just end up with an empty list when getting it straight from the site.

Comment: Have you checked that your `for img in...` loop is actually finding anything?

Comment: Yes, it prints a list of image alt text, but 5 star is not in that list.

Comment: Okay... when you look at the page source you'll see it's not in the page DOM. It comes from an XHR request and then javascript adds it to the page... If you open your browser's dev tools, you'll see the rating comes from: https://api.nhtsa.gov/vehicles/byYmmt?data=crashtestratings,safetyfeatures,recommendedfeatures&modelYear=2017&make=FORD&model=ESCAPE&trim=SUV&series=AWD&name= So I imagine you want to be loading the json data from that instead?

Comment: That was it, I didn't realize there was an API available. Thanks!

Comment: The reason you can't see 5 stars is because of dynamic loading, and API will be best way for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.nhtsa.gov/vehicle/2017/FORD/ESCAPE/SUV/AWD#safety-ratings-frontal' #url to retrieve data from
page = s.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all('div'): #lists all image alt text
    for img in div.find_all('img', alt=True):
        print(img['alt'])
```